# Apply Python function to multiple Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to write a function and apply it to multiple fields in a pandas dataframe. 
The function takes column colA1, and assigns a value to a new column, colB2 based on conditional statements. 
This function works if a single column is given, e.g. colA1, but how could I write it to iterate through a
list of columns, returning a corresponding number of new columns?

The following function works on a single column:

```
dict = {'colA1':[2,6,8,28,5], 
    'colA2': [38,6,14,63,3], 
    'colA3':[90,40,80,98,3]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

def function(x):
    if x <= 10:
        return '<= 10'
    elif x > 10:
        return '> 10' 

df['colB1']=df['colA1'].apply(function)

df['colB1']
```

This returns:

```
0    <= 10
1    <= 10
2    <= 10
3    > 10
4    <= 10
```

I attempted to apply it to multiple columns as shown here:
[Update Multiple Columns using Pandas Apply Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55730100/update-multiple-columns-using-pandas-apply-function)

```
df[['colB1', 'colB2', 'colB3']]=df[['colA1', 'colA2', 'colA3']].apply(function)
```

But this returns: 
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index colA1')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this actually what you want to do, a faster alternative is [`np.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
cond=[df<= 10,df > 10]
choice=['<= 10','> 10' ]
df[:]=np.select(cond,choice)
print(df)
```

---

```
   colA1  colA2  colA3
0  <= 10   > 10   > 10
1  <= 10  <= 10   > 10
2  <= 10   > 10   > 10
3   > 10   > 10   > 10
4  <= 10  <= 10  <= 10
```

You can also try with [`df.applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for your function:

```
df[['colA1','colA2','colA3']].applymap(function)
#df.applymap(function)
```

---

```
   colA1  colA2  colA3
0  <= 10   > 10   > 10
1  <= 10  <= 10   > 10
2  <= 10   > 10   > 10
3   > 10   > 10   > 10
4  <= 10  <= 10  <= 10
```

Comment: Also don't use `dict` as dictionary names since it overwrites the builtin python `dict` func.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([function(x['colA1']),function(x['colA2']),function(x['colA3'])]), axis=1).rename({0:'colA1',1:'colA2',2:'colA3'}, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   colA1  colA2  colA3
0  <= 10   > 10   > 10
1  <= 10  <= 10   > 10
2  <= 10   > 10   > 10
3   > 10   > 10   > 10
4  <= 10  <= 10  <= 10
```